# Localhost Java Applet Keeps Crashing

Tags: java, crash, applet, localhost

I'm having a problem running my java applet on my localhost server. I was watching bucky's (thenewboston) video tutorials for java and can't seem to run my first java applet on my localhost website. The Java applet works great when testing in eclipse. I keep getting a "Java(TM) Platform SE 7 U25 has crashed." I know my java code is good (because it works in eclipse) and I followed his tutorial exactly on how to place it on a webpage.

My HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <head>
    <meta charset = "UTF-8"/>
    <title>My First Applet</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <applet code = "index.class" width = "400" height = "100"></applet>
  </body>
</html>
```

My java file:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class index extends JApplet{

  public void paint(Graphics g){

    super.paint(g);

    g.drawString("Wow this actually worked!", 25, 25);
  }
}
```

I compiled the java file to get index.class and have them in my localhost directory. Am I doing something wrong? :(

**Edit: I accessed it through my laptop on the same network and it works fine. It's just not working on my desktop. My desktop OS is Windows 7. Would that have any effect on it? I also checked other sites that run java, and none of them work on my desktop pc.**

Answer (score 0):

Are you using google chrome? Because there is sometimes an error when multiple versions of Java are installed with chrome. See: http://answer.techbuddiesonline.com/thread.php?elem_id=688

Comment: Yes I am, but I also tested it in FireFox (which just closes the browser when the page loads) and i checked IE also, which just freezes for about 10 seconds then just shows a blank screen.

Comment: I would still try uninstalling all versions of Java then reinstalling the latest one. If that doesn't work, I'm quite stumped - your code looks fine to me (except I would capitalize the class name as a java convention).